# MassTransit Activity Compensate method never called

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have cloned example app from here: https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Courier.

Running with default setup, I can see compensate queue in RabbitMQ, and Activities Execute methods are called, but Compensate method never called, and no messages in compensate queue were observed. I tried both returning  FaultContext() and throwing exception from Execute method.

Do I need to add something to initial code setup to Compensate flow work?

Comment: A previous activity in the routing slip must complete, with log, in order for compensate to be called. If an activity faults (throwing an exception) it's own compensate method is not called because it never completed.

Comment: thanks for your comment, it was my fault, did not pass logEntry in context.Completed in activities Execute method.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!